# What happen if I didn't put all the C* hosts in DevCenter?

Tags: cassandra

Let's say I have 4 nodes: host1, host2, host3 and host4. However I only add host1 and host2 as Contact hosts. What would happen if I perform any operation in DevCenter? Will the action propagate to host3 and host4? Will this cause data corruption?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what will happen:

1. DevCenter will use the Whitelist load balancing policy [1](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/WhiteListPolicy.html) to connect to the provided nodes

   While DevCenter uses the DataStax Java driver as the underlying connector, it does use the above mentioned load balancing policy to reduce the time needed to obtain connections (instead of the default driver's load balancing policy which requires discovering all the nodes in the cluster and initiating connection pools to all those)
2. DevCenter will send the request to the nodes in the list you provided
3. If data is local to these nodes they will take care of the requests. If data is found on the other nodes in the cluster, the nodes used for the connection will act as coordinators (basically they'll relay the requests to the nodes having the data)

Bottom line there's no risk of data corruption and the results you get will be exactly the same as for connecting to all the nodes.